Migrate certain taxonomy vocabularies
I am trying to migrate taxonomy terms from Drupal 7 to 10. I am using the migrate, migrate_plus and migrate_upgrade module.
I would like to import only a select few taxonomy vocabularies but cannot find a way.
Have tried the suggestion on the following thread but it doesn't work. Migrate only taxonomy terms from a specific vocabulary
To the migrate_upgrade generated YAML files, i added the following filter but no luck still gives the whole list.
source:
  plugin: d7_taxonomy_term
  bundle:
    - machine_name1
    - machine_name2

Have also tried
source:
  plugin: d7_taxonomy_vocabulary
  bundle: [authors, journals]


If you check core/modules/taxonomy/src/Plugin/migrate/source/d7/Term.php you can see an example for multiple vocabularies. It looks like

source:
plugin: d7_taxonomy_term
bundle: [tags, forums]
You also need the right indentation. Can you show a longer snippet of the migration file?


Thanks you are correct about the comment in Term.php, unfortunately that code does not work for me, maybe a core bug. I have added with the correct indentation but still no luck

Some remarks: 1. Your example uses the plugin "d7_taxonomy_vocabulary" which will not return any terms (but vocabularies instead), this is confusing. 2. You could also try using a copy of web/core/modules/taxonomy/migrations/d7_taxonomy_term.yml and see if any term is being found in the source. 3. What does the drush command migrates:status show? (you need the module migrate_tools for this). 4. Try migrate_devel to see if there is any data in the source. 5. I doubt there is a core bug because I recently managed to migrate terms using this method

I see the confusion, i'm using migrate_upgrade which generates the yaml files for each migration item. It's within that file where the bundle filter is not working as i was expecting.
Using: d7_taxonomy_term - i get each item from both bundles created as a taxonomy vocab (so bundle working)
Using: d7_taxonomy_vocabulary - i get every vocabulary created (bundle not working).
I may try by not using the migrate_upgrade yaml config file instead.

There's a new module called Migrate Wizard, for a straight forward task like migrating the terms it should have you sorted pretty quick. Everything's done from the UI, there's no coding, YAML or settings to change.
https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_wizard
All the best.
